# PowerShell Get-ChildItem full path is truncated

Tags: powershell

I'm capturing the file full path and last modified date in a text file but few directories with longer path gets truncated. Is it possible to get the full path without truncation or `...`.

Code I used:

```cs
Get-ChildItem -Path "\\server\xyz_data\devdata\fail logs\xxx\yyy\2012\01june2012\" -Recurse |
    select -Property Filename, LastWriteTime |
    Out-File -Encoding Ascii -Append d:/file.txt
```

Output:

```
server\xyz_data\devdata\fail logs\xxx\yyy\2012\01june2012\text123..... 22/03/2012 11.23.00
```

Is there any restrictions on number of characters to captured?

Comment: Use `Export-Csv` instead of `Out-File`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, because of the spaces in between the parameters like `- recurse`, and the missing hyphen in the `Out-File` cmdlet, your code should not run at all..
Also, I think you mean `FullName` instead of `filename`.

Try

```
Get-childitem -Path "\\server\xyz_data\devdata\fail logs\xxx\yyy\2012\01june2012\" -Recurse | 
    Select-Object -Property FullName, LastWriteTime |
    Export-Csv -Path 'd:/file.csv' -Force -NoTypeInformation
```

P.S. I used `Export-Csv` to output the results to file

Comment: The additional spaces were probably just a copy/paste issue or typo, since the OP apparently got output from their code, so I fixed them in the question.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yes, I saw the fixes you made right after I posted. Had to do an edit myself because initially I left a testing folder path in ;)

Comment: ASCII is not a good choice, especially for filesystems names, which are Unicode. How about `UTF8`?

Comment: @TomBlodget you're absolutely right. In fact, leaving the encoding parameter out in PS < 6.0 defaults to ASCII encoding. As of version 6.0, the default value for `-Encoding` is UTF8NoBOM.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's fullname, not filename.  It seems like out-file pipes it through format-table first, and depending on the width of your window will truncate the filename.  Out-file also encodes in unicode.  Export-csv is the way to go.  Interestingly, piping to set-content instead would save it as hashtables.