# Powershell3.0 Export csv append

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to append output to a text file using `Export-Csv`

```
Get-childitem -path 'path' | select-object - property filename | export-csv -path 'f:/test.txt' -append -encoding ascii -force -notypeinformation
```

But it's getting overwritten every time the path changes.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you remove `-force`, do you get an error?

Comment: I need to remove notypeinformation as well. If not it throws error

Comment: i don't have ps3 available, but on ps5.1 it errors [without the `-Force`] and states that it cannot append to the file since the new data does not match the header of the existing file. if i add `-Force`, then there is no error ... but there is no change in the file, either. ///// what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to capture full file path and its last modified date  onto a text file. But few filename are big so its truncated while using out-file so I used export-csv but it's not appending. I use ascii encoding to print every folder in new line .

Comment: You aren't capturing the last modified date, only the file path.

Comment: I didn't added that in the code above but to create basic code which will work,so I'm just trying with the fullname

Comment: As with your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56757047/powershell-get-childitem-full-path-is-truncated), you need to take away the space between `-` and `property`. Also, if you want the full path and filename, use the property `FullName`, not `filename`. Remove the `-Force` switch and the `-Encoding Ascii` aswell.